# Por que esse loop é infinito?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop

Eu queria que parasse o loop quando t estiver em 5. Por isso coloquei contagem -1, mas ele não volta para `while` para checar a condição e vira um *loop* infinito.

```
text = 'abcdefghij'
t = 10

while t != 5:
    for i in text:
        print(i)
        t -= 1
        print(t)
´´´´
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variável **t** não esta sendo utilizada da forma correta. 
A partir do momento que você entra no segundo loop ele vai sempre percorrer as letras de **text** decrementando 1 em **t**

```
while t != 5:
    for i in text:
       print(i)
       t -= 1
       print(t)
```

Ao fim da primeira interação no **segundo** loop, o `for i in text:`, o valor de **t** é 0. Ele sai do loop e 0 ainda é diferente de 5. Ele entra novamente no loop for e quando sai o valor é -9 e assim por diante.

O valor de **t** sempre será diferente de 5

Answer (score 7):

Esse código não faz muito sentido e é bem ineficiente, mas se quer realmente fazer o que está descrito na pergunta ele seria assim:

```
text = 'abcdefghij'
t = 10
for i in text:
    print(i)
    t -= 1
    print(t)
    if t == 5:
        break
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/djqALY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Forbreakpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ForBreak.py).

Você não tem um algoritmo que exija uma laço dentro do outro, você provavelmente usou um `while` quando só queria um `if`.

Não é o mais comum mas como precisa parar algo no meio o mais correto neste caso talvez seja fazer só o `while`:

```
text = 'abcdefghij'
t = 10
while t != 5:
    print(text[10 - t])
    t -= 1
    print(t)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/k3FvsH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Whilepy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/While.py).